# Is there a way to programmatically minimize a window

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

What I'm doing is I have a full-screen form, with no title bar, and consequently lacks the minimize/maximize/close buttons found in the upper-right hand corner. I'm wanting to replace that functionality with a keyboard short-cut and a context menu item, but I can't seem to find an event to trigger to minimize the form.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

```
private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
     if(e.KeyChar == 'm')
         this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
}
```

Answer (score 37):

```
FormName.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
```

Answer (score 26):

in c#.net

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
```

Answer (score 11):

```
<form>.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
```

Answer (score 8):

```
Form myForm;
myForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
```

Answer (score 3):

There's no point minimizing an already minimized form. So here we go:

```
if (form_Name.WindowState != FormWindowState.Minimized) form_Name.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
```

Answer (score 1):

`this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;`

Answer (score 0):

-- c#.net

NORMALIZE
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;

this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;

Answer (score -1):

```
this.MdiParent.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
```

Answer (score -4):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

Me.Hide()

End Sub
```

Comment: hiding not the same as minimizing