# C# Minimize Whole Application

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is there a possible way in Visual Studio that you are able to minimize your whole application? I tried this:

```
private void button4_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
}
```

There is an error which is `'System.Windows.Forms.Application' does not contain a definition for 'WindowState'` which means (if you didn't already know) that the application as a whole doesn't have a window factor (this I already knew) but is there a way to minimize all the windows in an application all at once?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to programmatically minimize a window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69352/is-there-a-way-to-programmatically-minimize-a-window). You shouldn't need to do it to `Application` - it obviously is a different type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
foreach (Form form in Application.OpenForms)
{
    form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply loop through all of the open forms in your application and set their `WindowState property to "Minimized"`. Get the OpenForms collection for your Application class.

```
private void button4_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var form in Application.OpenForms)
    {
        form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
    }
}
```